# KeyboardAvoidingView collapses all inner components when contains one View

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When using KeyboardAvoidingView with behavior="position" property and if that KeyboardAvoidingView component contains one View with multiple items in it, all inner components are collapsed one over the other, as if flex == 0 for all of them:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEG3V.png)

Here is an example (Input is a react-native-elements component based on TextInput):

```
return (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior="position"
    style={{
      flex: 1
    }}
  >
    <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
      <Input
        value={email}
        keyboardAppearance="light"
        autoFocus={false}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        keyboardType="email-address"
        returnKeyType="next"
        placeholder={"Email"}
        containerStyle={{
          marginLeft: 10
        }}
        errorMessage={
          !isEmailValid
            ? "Please enter a valid email address"
            : undefined
        }
      />
      <Input
        value={password}
        keyboardAppearance="light"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        returnKeyType={"done"}
        blurOnSubmit={true}
        containerStyle={{
          marginLeft: 10
        }}
        placeholder={"Password"}
        errorMessage={
          isEmailValid && !isPasswordValid
            ? "Please enter at least 8 characters"
            : undefined
        }
      />
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>)
```

If I change the property to behavior="padding" it becomes fine as expected, but I am not interested in "padding" behavior.

Comment: Can you provide example at https://snack.expo.io/?

Comment: Here you go:
https://snack.expo.io/SkK9q0R0M

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I got tired from trying to get KeyboardAvoidingView to work as expected and I was able to achieve what I needed using [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) which is a simple and powerful library.

Here's a code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const email = '';
        const password = '';

        return (
                <KeyboardAwareScrollView 
                    style={{
                        flex: 1
                    }}
                    scrollEnabled={false}>
                    <Input
                        value={email}
                        placeholder={'Email'}
                    />
                    <Input
                        value={password}
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                    />
                </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help [Aung Myat Hein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679544/aung-myat-hein).

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is what you expected.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const email = '';
        const password = '';

        return (
            <ScrollView >
                <KeyboardAvoidingView
                    behavior="position"
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        paddingTop: 50
                    }}>
                    <Input
                        value={email}
                        placeholder={'Email'}
                    />
                    <Input
                        value={password}
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                    />
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is expo snack https://snack.expo.io/rkPA0C00f

Comment: Almost but not quite yet. All components get stuck on top of the screen without spreading throughout the View. See here for example: https://snack.expo.io/HkKSBEJ1X

Answer (score 0):

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior={'position'}
keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 24}
>
```

Comment: Your answer needs some more explanation what to do.